# Show excerpts of posts on P2 Home page

Tags: excerpt, theme-p2

I am looking to show the latest posts on my site home page, which is using P2 theme. I want them to be shown in excerpts.

I have found the following code on a site, it said its in the `entry.php` file.
Change,

```
<?php elseif ( 'post' == p2_get_the_category() ) : ?> <?php p2_title(); ?> <?php the_content( __( '(More ...)' , 'p2' ) ); ?> <?php else : ?>
```

to:

```
<?php elseif ( !is_singular() ) : ?> <?php p2_title(); ?> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> <?php else
```

When I looked in the `entry.php` file, I can not see this code, so I can only assume it was an outdated P2 theme. 
Does anyone know what code I need to change in the updated P2